# Unable to share Image using Intent Share Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

Trying to send Image to Facebook and Whatsapp by using Intent Share. However, there seems no error in code, 
but unable to send it in Whatsapp and Facebook, it gives a toast :

> Sharing failed, please try again

Here is the code I use, wonder what is causing this?

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
public void shareIt(View view)
{
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///data/user/0/obx.com.futurister/files/newImage.jpg"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your android version is marshmallow you should turn on storage permission  for Facebook and WhatsApp.